# Tools for testing web vulnerability

Tags: security

I am looking into the possibility of using tools in order to help me evaluate my site's vulnerability. The ones i have liked the most are [Nikto2](http://www.cirt.net/nikto2) and [SensePost](http://www.sensepost.com/labs/tools/pentest/wikto).

Before actually deciding, i thought it would be smart to ask around for opinions: anybody has had any experience with any of these? Does someone knows of any tool which could be better? Looking forward to hearing some opinions!! :)

Comment: Nikto Tutorial : [here](http://dasunhegoda.com/nikto-web-vulnerability-scanner-tutorial-imawhitehat/893/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear [Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus) is pretty good, not sure if they have a free liscence though.

If you have corporate backing, you could spring for a [Qualys](http://www.qualys.com/) scanner.

If you are going the free route, Nikto is fine, an nmap scan never hurts either. Just make sure you have the latest software and patches, and know how XSS / Injection attacks work.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking for something somewhere along the free route, however in case this doesn't turn out i'll have no choice but to pay. I have looked into the Nessus tool.. but it lacks the functionality of running scheduled tasks which is somewaht important to me. Have you used the Qualys scanner? Do you know if it provides this functionality? Because i wasn't able to find it. thks!

Comment: @Soph, Yes I have played around with a Qualys scanner, they are very thorough, and do have the functionality to schedule scans. Pricey though, so if it is for a personal website I don't know how applicable that would be, they are more geared to larger environments.

Comment: I forgot to tick your answer! I am using Qualys and have found it to be a very reliable tool, so thank you very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for application security (HTTP) or network security?  Nessus and Qualys have historically focused on network security and have performed poorly at web application security testing.  Nmap does almost no testing unless you enable a few scripts then it does basic enumeration.  You should learn how to do manual testing with Burp or ZAP, but Nikto, W3af, grendlescan, or any other free scanner will help you find vulns.  You really need to understand the vulns.  I'd use Burp Suite (Pro if possible) or ZAP (I've heard it's good) to do an assessment.  Dirbuster and google are good enumeration tools.

Answer (score 0):

You must Try [Scan Titan](http://www.scantitan.com) it is free and also tested all known security vulnerabilities, I tested it and it gives good results.

Comment: As a free can be considered to be good anyway.